# maxQueryStringLength for 256 characters throwing exception

Tags: url

I have made following configuration in web.config file in my asp.net mvc3 application.

```
<system.web>

<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="4.0" maxUrlLength="6000" 

maxQueryStringLength="6000" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"  />

</system.web>
```

Still I am receiving following error for maxQueryStringLength = 256.

The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength value.

Help required.

Thanks,
Harish

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the max is also set in IIS.

See link: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits